# Issue with arrays and methods (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, methods, reverse, alternate

The assignment was to accept an array 'a', pick up alternate values from 'a', store them in reverse order in another array 'b' and print the values of 'b'. 
I wrote the following code, but the values of 'b' getting printed are all 0.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Assignment
{
    public int[] array(int[] a)
    {
        int l=a.length;
        int x=l-1;
        int[] b=new int[l];
        for(int i=x;i>=0;i=-2)
        {
            b[x-i]=a[i];
        }
        return b;
     }

    public static void main()throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Assignment asg=new Assignment();
        System.out.println("How many numbers do you want in the array?");
        int l=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers");

        int[] a =new int[l];
        for(int i=0;i<l;i++) 
            a[i]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        int[] b=asg.array(a);
        for(int j=0;j<l;j++) 
            System.out.println(b[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing the main method signature change the code to as follows:

```
try
        {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        MainClass asg=new MainClass();
        System.out.println("How many numbers do you want in the array?");
        int l=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers");
        int[] a =new int[l];
        for(int i=0;i<l;i++) a[i]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int[] b=asg.array(a);
        int newSize = 0;
        if(l% 2 == 0)
            newSize = l/2;
        else
            newSize = (l/2) +1;
        for(int j=0;j<newSize;j++) System.out.println(b[j]);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


public int[] array(int[] a)
        {
            int l=a.length;
            int x=l-1;
            int newSize = 0;
            if(l% 2 == 0)
                newSize = l/2;
            else
                newSize = (l/2) +1;

            int[] b=new int[newSize];
            int i = 0;
            while(x >= 0)
                {
                    b[i]=a[x];
                    i++;
                    x -= 2;
                }

            return b;
         }
```

The length of b should be half of a and not same as a.

Comment: The code works perfectly, thank you. Although I removed the catch(Exception ex) block because I got an error that 'try' statement was missing and that we aren't allowed to use anything out of syllabus (high school education is sometimes restrictive). Anyway, I appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

The `main` method signature is not right and check this `i=-2` condition.

Answer (score 0):

main method signature must look like this :

```
 public static void main(String s[]){
        ....
}
```

here in `for()` loop i should be decremented by 1;

```
public int[] array(int[] a)
        {
            int l=a.length;
            int x=l-1;
            int[] b=new int[l];
            for(int i=x;i>=0;i--)  // decrement i by 1;
            {
                b[x-i]=a[i];
            }
            return b;
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your prgram would not compile - main() method has wrong signature. 
Use

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
...
}
```

Then change loop storing values in new array to:

```
for(int i = x; i >= 0; i--) {
    b[x - i] = a[i];
}
```

Comment: I don't have enough 'reputation' to downvote. And i don't know who voted you down or why.